# How to fix czech language characters after SAS7BDAT import into Python

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, sas

I need to import a sas7bdat file into Python. One column of the data are strings containing Czech language words. If I try to import it, the Czech language letters are missing.

I've already tried to use pandas pd.read_sas. However, I have in different column large date and pd.read_sas gets error described [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/28047) (SAS7BDAT however, is ok with large date). Below I copied an example of reduced data (only one row one column dataset)
[This is a picture of test dataset ddd24 in SAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOblD.png)

```
import pandas as pd
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT
df7=SAS7BDAT('..\Kreditky\ddd24.sas7bdat').to_data_frame()
print(df7)

Expected=      Střední odborné
Actual result= Stedn odborn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `encoding='utf-8'` as in

```
df7=SAS7BDAT('..\Kreditky\ddd24.sas7bdat', encoding='utf-8').to_data_frame()
```

If that doesn't work either, try to find the exact encoding of your input. E.g. `encoding='iso-8859-1'`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I used proc contents data=ddd24; run; in SAS to get the encoding I needed.